# Can I use multiple parameters for the function findElements in selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Can I use `findElements()` in selenium WebDriver, with multiple `By`s.

That is can I use `findElements(By.tagName() & By.className())` in Selenium?

Comment: What context is this being placed in? What application are you developing?

Comment: I believe it is the same as using xpath. You can write as complex query as you wish.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following syntax:

```
driver.findElement(new ByChained(By.id("foo"),By.xpath("//*[.=’ABCD’]")));
```

You can see this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/8wFpuiAUGLk) for more details:

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. You can do something like:

   ```
   WebElement parentEl = driver.findElement(By.tagName(""))
   WebElement childEl = parentEl.findElement(By.className(""))
   ```
2. Use the PageFactory `@FindBys`. See [Selenium PageFactory](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) and [Selenium API](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBys.html).